# Tracking Number Guessing Attempts using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple number guessing game numberGuess() that tracks the # of attempts a player takes, but does not track an attempt if the player guesses a number that has already been guessed.

The only bug that keeps happening is if the player guesses the 1st number he guesses more than once - the game then logs that attempt when it shouldn't.  However, if the player guesses any other number, but the first one more than once, it works perfectly.

For example, if player guesses in this order: 2, 5, 2, 3, the total attempts SHOULD show 3, but it shows 4.

However, if player guesses in this order 2, 5, 5, 3, the total attempts correctly shows 3.

I have hours and hours tinkering with this code and trying to figure this out before asking here, but have hit a wall.  It seems to be a simple fix that I cannot figure out.  Please let me know if you have spotted the error to fix this small bug!

```js
function numberGuess () {
 var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1); // Generates a random number between 0 and 100

 var totalGuesses = []; // Array to stores all the guesses
  
  var guess = Number(prompt("Welcome to number guess!  Guess a number between 1 and 100")); // Prompts guessor to guess first number
  
 while (guess != number) { //loop runs while user has not guessed the number

  if (!guess) { // User cancels prompts
   return;
  }
  else if (totalGuesses.indexOf(guess) >= 0) { // Checks to see if guess has already been guessed
   guess = prompt ("You already guessed that number before.  Give me another guess.");
  }
  else {
   totalGuesses.push(guess);
   if (guess > number) {
    guess = prompt ("Your number is too high.  Try Again.  Don't give up!");
   }

   else { 
    guess = prompt ("Your number is too low.  Try Again.  I know you can do it!");
   }
  }
 }
 
 // Guess is correct!    

 alert("Congratulations!  You guessed the number!  It took you " + (totalGuesses.length +1) + " attempts!"); 
};

numberGuess();
```

Comment: where are you adding `guess` to `totalGuesses`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following branch of your if statement:

```
else if (totalGuesses.indexOf(guess) >= 0) { // Checks to see if guess has already been guessed
   guess = prompt ("You already guessed that number before.  Give me another guess.");
}
```

In this code, you're not adding the guess to the `totalGuesses` array because it has already been guessed. As a result, the number of items in the `totalGuesses` array remains the same even though the number of guesses has increased by one.

A hacky solution would be to add the guess to the `totalGuesses` array anyway. But a better solution would be to use the `totalGuesses` as a set (unique values only) and make use of a counter variable which starts at 0 to track the number of guesses a user has made.

Furthermore, although you're correct in assuming that indexes in an array begin at 0, the `length` property of the array returns the number of items in the array, which, even if the index starts at 0, will always return the correct number of items. Therefore you don't need to add 1 to the result.

```
alert("Congratulations!  You guessed the number!  It took you " + totalGuesses.length + " attempts!");
```

Something that I've also noticed is that if the user enters something other than a number on his/her first guess, the code will correctly convert it to a number, however if the user then enters something that isn't a number after his/her first guess, it will remain as a string.